# "Unable to locate libcv-dev" when installing OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to install OpenCV on my Linux system. Bearing in mind that I am using Linux from a bootable USB drive, I tried installing this but it produces this error:

```
 ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libcv-dev
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Unable to locate package libcv-dev"
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the old package unless you have to. [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation) is a guide for installing OpenCV on Ubuntu from source. If you're not comfortable with source, you might try [this guy's](https://launchpad.net/~limparissoft/+archive/opencv-ppa) OpenCV 2.4.5 Ubuntu PPA.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. 
OpenCv is rather difficult to get out of the box. There are a number of different methods you could resort to.

1 . Try using the package manager to search for opencv packages and install them.

2 .  Its possible there's a problem related to your package manager/OS.

You could try installing opencv through the package manager on a different operating system. You could try creating a virtual box image if this is a convenient way to test this.

3 . Just download OpenCV and just link against it ... who needs a package manager anyway ...

Guides on how to use OpenCV with [netbeans](http://blog.eyalarubas.com/2012/10/23/opencv-installation-on-windows-netbeans-mingw/) and [Code Blocks](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CodeBlocks) for example.

4 . if you don't can't find opencv compiled the way that you want, download the source code and [CMAKE](http://www.cmake.org/). CMake will [prepare](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeBhwbRoKvk) your source code depending on what options you select. When cmake is done, you can compile opencv using your chosen C++ compiler. 
Once opencv has been compiled, you can link against it as in option 3.

Comment: Another option is to download EMGU and compile it using monodevelop or Visual studio. Although this might not be a good option for you if you need to use C++. It is however the quickest and easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, just update and reboot and you'll be able to find it:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```